# Prisma 2 unable to fetch DateTime column with null value

Tags: prisma2

```
      await this.prisma.fee_collections.findMany({
        where: whereClauseWithTransactionDateCondition,
        include: {
            student_master: {
                select: {
                    fee_start_month: true,
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

In my DB, fee_start_month column schema :

fee_start_month                   DateTime?                 @db.Date

At the fee_start_month column, some of the values are null so prisma2 unable to fetch those records, and It's thrown an exception.

Generated Error :
[Nest] 21275   - 15/03/2021, 13:09:21   [ExceptionsHandler]
Invalid `prisma.fee_collections.findMany()` invocation:

Value out of range for the type. The column `fee_start_month` contained an invalid DateTime value with either day or month set to zero. +3337ms

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5006

Comment: YES, Thank you for the comment.
I update all blank DateTime column values with NULL & now it's working.
My code logic problem -  update the fee_start_month column with blank text.